# Plotting the sleep/wait chain of a process

Tags: pipe, proc, sleep, strace

I often want to know why a process in the middle of a pipeline is sleeping and not busy processing data.  My current method is:

1. find the `pid` of interest
2. `sudo strace -pt pid` to get the blocking syscall and object (fd, child, futex, etc.)
3. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to detach strace
4. look up the appropriate object in `/proc/pid`
5. `grep /proc/` or use `lsof` to find the other end of the pipe or process being waited on
6. repeat from #1 with the new `pid`

This is a pretty slow process that combines a lot of tools that don't play well together (`strace` in particular is hard to automate).  Is there a tool that will do this loop for me and plot out the wait chain of a process, or at least make one iteration less awkward?

Linux 3.2, Ubuntu LTS 12, x64, under VirtualBox, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

most `ps` s now include a tree option, or a very aptly name related utility, `ptree`.

As my current work system doesn't have ptree, I currently use

```
ps fauw
```

I think I also had a

```
ps taux (t making more sense than f)
```

Finally some ps have options to also include a programs threads in the view.

While this isn't the automated solution you (and I) would wish for, my experience is that there emerges a list of 'likely-suspects' in process trees, and just scanning the tree, you can often guess where the problem is.

IHTH

Comment: `ptree` has nothing to do with wait chains. If a process is blocking, you have no reason to believe that this is because of a child process.